# How to use burst / slow-mo features on Nexus 6p?

Tags: camera, nexus-6p

The Nexus 6p is supposed to have some cool features dealing with burst and slow-motion (high frame rate) capture, but all my searches for how to use these features are turning up an explanation that the features are there, but not how to use them.

It must not be too difficult, because I inadvertantly took a burst capture when I was trying to take a single picture.   A bit of research suggest that "holding down" the shutter button (volume button, apparently) shoots a burst, which is unfortunate if I just want to make sure I really pressed the button and only want a single picture.  I can't find out a way to disable this if I really don't want a burst of images at a particular shoot.

But I can't figure out at all how to use 120fps or 240fps capture, or even how to choose the frame rate.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for Google Camera v3.0 and up:

**Video**

> Open Google Camera app
>
> Swipe from right to left for Video mode.
>
> In the top right, touch the icons to turn features on or off:
>
> **Slow motion**: Set slow motion to 120 fps or turn off slow motion.
>
> Note: On Nexus 6P devices, there's an option for 240 fps. 240 fps produces a higher quality slow motion video than 120 fps, but requires more storage space on your device.
>
> **Flash**: Turn flash on or off, or set to auto (for auto, you'll see an "A" in the icon).

**Photo**

> You can choose what Google Camera does with your photo bursts. There are two settings you can turn on or off:
>
> “SmartBurst”: Automatically save only the best photos in a burst.
>
> “Auto-generate creations”: Automatically turn your photo burst into an animation or collage.
>
> To turn these settings on or off:
>
> Open Google Camera app.
>
> At the top left, touch Menu  > Settings > Burst settings.
>
> Next to each setting, touch the switch to turn the it on or off.

For full details see:
See: https://support.google.com/googlecamera/#6306661